# Grouping two mySQL select statements under one alias and ordering that alias

Tags: mysql, union, alias

I want to run two mysql `SELECT` statements, combine them, call the new combination by its own name, then order that new combination by a user-defined function. This is what I am trying currently:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE def1 LIKE '$input%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE def2 LIKE '$input%'
) AS newcol
ORDER BY levenshtein('$input', newcol)
LIMIT 10
```

But I get the following error:

```
Unable to run query:Unknown column 'newcol' in 'order clause'
```

The problem is clearly with defining the new group 'newcol'.

Comment: but newcol isn't a column ?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to order by a TABLE, not by a FIELD! Use a field from your tables ant it'll go smooth